# Using Shark with MonoTouch, no symbols

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, shark

I'm trying to use Shark to profile a release build of my iPhone app but I don't have symbol information. Everything is "Unknown library" and hex addresses. I followed [these instructions](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Profiling) and added -nosymbolstrip -aot="iphone-abi" to Extra Arguments, but no luck.

This is on an iPhone 3G with OS version 3.1.2.

Just to see if it was due to my old OS version, I tried the same thing on my iPhone4 with 4.2.1 and I get a different issue. On that device, Shark won't even start profiling when I click Start.

Comment: I've never been able to get Shark working... Have you tried using instruments?

Comment: I can't get Shark to work and have failed to get anything meaningful out of Instruments either. Would love to get it working for MonoTouch apps.

Answer (score 0):

Shark is no longer supported in the most recent XCodes.  Use **Instruments**, instead.